# Why does Ubuntu One assume the files on the site are newer than the new ones on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I recently installed 11.04 on my new computer. After I installed copies of my files from an older computer, Ubuntu One insists that the files on that site are newer than the ones just installed on my new computer. I want the computer to have preeminence. Why are new files I just edited deleted from my computer? I want to back stuff up not delete it to make my computer look like what's on Ubuntu One! ---gk

Answer (score 1):

Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/503751

From the bugreport:

1. Open (or create if it doesn't exist): ~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf
2. Add the following 2 lines to this file and save:

   [**main**]

   log_level = DEBUG
3. Restart the Ubuntu One client
4. Try to reproduce the behavior you've been seeing and then attach the following log file: ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log to the bug.

Is is also discussed on ubuntuforums here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8656215

All from 2010 but I do not seem to be able to find a fix for this(...)